# How do I change the template being displayed after the user clicks a button?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I'm quite new to Django, so I aplogize if I am making dumb mistakes.
Here is the code I have so far:

For views.py:

```
def bylog(request):
    if request.POST.get('Filter'):
        return render(request, 'index.html', context)
    filtered_login = Invalid.objects.values_list('login').distinct()
    filtered = []
    for item in filtered_login:
        filtered.append(item[0])
    results = {'results': results, 'filtered': filtered}
    return render(request, 'bylog.html', context)
```

Here is a snippet of bylog.html:

```
<select id>"dropdown">
{% for item in filtered %}
    <option value={{ item }}">{{ item }}</option>
{% endfor %}
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Filter" name="Filter" />
```

My main goal is to get the value from the drop down list, and after the user clicks the `Filter` button, the value gets passed to another template.
Is that even possible?

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic for your goal I supose it is to manage  `POST` in django, meaning that you want to send any data/variables from a template to a view and then do any operation with it (send it to another template, or store...)

The basic for this is(Using HTML form, not Django form):

```
- Create a HTML form in the template 
- Add the selects/inputs with the data you want to manage and a button/input to make the post
- Manage the post in the view
```

**EXAMPLE**

**template form**

```
<form id="" method="post" action=".">
{% csrf_token %}
<select id="any_name" name="any_name">"dropdown">
{% for item in filtered %}
    <option value={{ item }}">{{ item }}</option>
{% endfor %}
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Filter" name="Filter" />

</form>
```

**view.py**

```
def your_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':  # If anyone clicks filter, you receive POST method
        data = request.POST['any_name']
        # Do what you need here with the data
        # You can call another template and send this data
        # You can change any_name for the variable you want, changing the name and id in the select

#Your view code
```

I recommend you to read about `Django forms` because if you need a bigger form, to manage the data of a model with a lot of fields, a `Django Form` will save you a lot of time

[Working with Django Forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/)

Comment: Wow, thank you for the detailed answer. I will definitely check it out. It says I need the csrf_token when trying to do what I did earlier, but I can do my research on that. Thanks a lot!

Comment: oh sorry I forgot to add the token, add `{% csrf_token %}` inside the form (I fixed the code, check now)